# Avoid Inputs Overflowing Their Container & Make Them Hop To Next Line When Resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add too many inputs (depending on how many i want) they overflow their container, and when i do have only two inputs for example they overflow the container when i resize the window.

Here is my html and css:

```css
#datails_container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 70%;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.theight {
    height: 26%;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
    background-color: #b50612;
    width: 92px;
    height: min-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#presentaion {
    color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

#detsubmitter {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 6px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 2.6em;
}

#detsubmitter:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemcount {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: .6em 1.4em .6em 1.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    border-radius: .5em;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: -76px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 39px;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    left: -65px;
    height: min-content;
    width: 79.9667px !important;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

input {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: -53px;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: left !important;
}
```

```html
    <div id="datails_container"  >
  <form id="" action="" method="post">
      <div id="genre_cont" class="theight" style="margin-top: 75px;">
          <span>Genres</span>
          <select name="gnerenmbr" class="itemcount" id="gnerenmbr">
              <option value="01">1</option>
              <option value="02">2</option>
              <option value="03">3</option>
              <option value="04">4</option>
              <option value="05">5</option>
              <option value="06">6</option>
              <option value="07">7</option>
              <option value="08">8</option>
              <option value="09">9</option>
          </select>
          <label for="gnerenmbr">genre(s):</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 4">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="language_cont" class="theight">
          <span>Languages</span>
          <select name="languagenmbr" class="itemcount" id="languagenmbr">
              <option value="01">1</option>
              <option value="02">2</option>
              <option value="03">3</option>
              <option value="04">4</option>
              <option value="05">5</option>
              <option value="06">6</option>
              <option value="07">7</option>
              <option value="08">8</option>
              <option value="09">9</option>
          </select>
          <label for="languagenmbr">Language(s):</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="country_cont" class="theight">
          <span>Countries</span>
          <select name="countrynmbr" class="itemcount" id="countrynmbr">
              <option value="01">1</option>
              <option value="02">2</option>
              <option value="03">3</option>
              <option value="04">4</option>
              <option value="05">5</option>
              <option value="06">6</option>
              <option value="07">7</option>
              <option value="08">8</option>
              <option value="09">9</option>
          </select>
          <label for="countrynmbr">country(ies):</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
          <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
      </div>
      <button id="detsubmitter" type="submit">ADD details</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

1. I don't want the inputs to *overflow* their container.
2. I want the input go to next line if it has no space when *resizing*.

Comment: Could you create a snippet so we can run the code and better help you?

Comment: yes i will add the snippet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```css
#datails_container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 70%;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.theight {
    /* height: 26%; */
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
    background-color: #b50612;
    width: 92px;
    height: min-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#presentaion {
    color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

#detsubmitter {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 6px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 2.6em;
}

#detsubmitter:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemcount {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: .6em 1.4em .6em 1.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    border-radius: .5em;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: -76px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 39px;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    top: 28px;
    height: min-content;
    width: 79.9667px !important;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

input {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    /* top: 25px; */
    /* left: -53px; */
    margin: 20px;
    float: left !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To DO App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-Scale = 1.0" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <header>
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="inputDiv">
        <input type="text" id="inputTask" placeholder="Enter new task here...">
        <button id="addBtn" onclick="add()">add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tabLink active" onclick="tabLinkClick(this,'all')">All</button>
        <button class="tabLink" onclick="tabLinkClick(this,'active')">Active</button>
        <button class="tabLink" onclick="tabLinkClick(this,'complete')">Completed</button>
    </div>
    <div class="table" id="todoListTable">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >
                nothing to do...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> -->

    <div id="datails_container"  >
       
        
        <form id="" action="" method="post">
            <div id="genre_cont" class="theight" style="margin-top: 75px;">
                <span>Genres</span>
                <select name="gnerenmbr" class="itemcount" id="gnerenmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="gnerenmbr">genre(s):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 4">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="language_cont" class="theight">
                <span>Languages</span>
                <select name="languagenmbr" class="itemcount" id="languagenmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="languagenmbr">Language(s):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="country_cont" class="theight">
                <span>Countries</span>
                <select name="countrynmbr" class="itemcount" id="countrynmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="countrynmbr">country(ies):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
            </div>
            <button id="detsubmitter" type="submit">ADD details</button>
        </form>
    </div>



</html>
```

if set display: flex; and  flex-wrap: wrap; and align-content: space-around;your problem solve and you can set other style for look better

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of the position issue. Refer to the below code for better understanding. I have commented on some of your code and added two or three lines.

```css
#datails_container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    width: 70%;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50px;
    /*bottom: 0;*/
    /*left: 0;*/
    /*right: 0;*/
    margin: auto;
    /*background-color: black;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.theight {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
    /*display: flex;*/
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
    background-color: #b50612;
    width: 92px;
    height: min-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    left: 12px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#presentaion {
    color: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

#detsubmitter {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 6px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 2.6em;
}

#detsubmitter:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.itemcount {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: .6em 1.4em .6em 1.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    border-radius: .5em;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*top: 15px;*/
    /*left: -76px;*/
    display: flex;
    /*margin-left: 39px;*/
}

label {
    /*position: relative;*/
    top: 28px;
    left: -65px;
    height: min-content;
    width: 79.9667px !important;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
}

input {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    /*top: 25px;*/
    /*left: -53px;*/
    /*margin-right: auto;*/
    /*float: left !important;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="datails_container"  >
       
        
        <form id="" action="" method="post">
            <div id="genre_cont" class="theight" style="margin-top: 75px;">
                <span>Genres</span>
                <select name="gnerenmbr" class="itemcount" id="gnerenmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="gnerenmbr">genre(s):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 4">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="language_cont" class="theight">
                <span>Languages</span>
                <select name="languagenmbr" class="itemcount" id="languagenmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="languagenmbr">Language(s):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 3">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="country_cont" class="theight">
                <span>Countries</span>
                <select name="countrynmbr" class="itemcount" id="countrynmbr">
                    <option value="01">1</option>
                    <option value="02">2</option>
                    <option value="03">3</option>
                    <option value="04">4</option>
                    <option value="05">5</option>
                    <option value="06">6</option>
                    <option value="07">7</option>
                    <option value="08">8</option>
                    <option value="09">9</option>
                </select>
                <label for="countrynmbr">country(ies):</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="input 2">
            </div>
            <button id="detsubmitter" type="submit">ADD details</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank yo although the last container get over its own container but i can fix it.